# visual vm analyze memory leak

Tags: java, spring, visualvm

in my visual vm, i click on sample->memory, and i keep see "windowprincipal" class, instances stay at 25. even that right now nobody using the application. is this sign of memory leak?

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?c069df48c2.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying requesting a Garbage Collection multiple times and then see this graph again. If the object instances are still there than you can trace the patch of these objects i.e., who is referencing these objects and from that you can assess if this is a memory leak or just legitimate objects which are cached.

Comment: my graph look ok. up and down. but just wondering the screenshot above, the "instance" mean counter of times class instances accumulated  OR  "instance" mean , currently at this moment, that is numbers of instances of class 'still inside memory'

Comment: it means at this time this many instances of class still inside the memory.

Check here http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/heapdump.html for more information.